# How to add colours to GNU Screen

Tags: colors, gnu-screen

This might seem like an odd/silly question(and I'm not entirely sure this is the right place to ask?), but I have some server programs running on a  machine and I'd like multiple terminals to monitor them with, so I have installed GNU Screen. I was just wondering if there was a way to add custom colours to the program, e.g. the borders between windows and the default white font. I can see that it can be done as I have seen images of a coloured session, but I can't find anything about in on the internet or the manual. If anyone knows, any help would be appreciated!